# Issue with JSON request - rails/faraday

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, curl, faraday

I have an issue with rails and faraday when I try to receive access token which should be included in a JSON response from the external Api.

What I want to do is user authentication based on external API.
I assume that the User already has valid credentials (in this case email as username and password).

Now when he connects to my Api, I send JSON request to the external Api to verify whether this user is valid and wait for access token.

Once the access token is sent in a response, user authentication is successful and I have access to the other endpoints

This is my controller

```
module Api
  class AuthenticationController < ApplicationController
    def create 
      client = XXX::AuthClient.new

      response = client.authenticate(
        email: params[:email],
        password: params[:password]
      )

      api_client = XXX::Client.new(response[:access_token])

      if response[:access_token]
        api_user = api_client.get_user()

        if api_user["id"]
          db_user = User.create(xxx_id: api_user["id"], xxx_access_token: response[:access_token])
        end
      end

      render json: { access_token: db_user.access_token }
    end
  end
end
```

And this is my AuthClient service

```
class AuthClient
    def initialize
      @http_client = Faraday.new('https://auth.xxx.com/')
    end

    def authenticate(email:, password:)
      headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }.to_json

      body = {
        grant_type: "password",
        username: email,
        password: password,
        client_id: "particularclientid",
        client_secret: "particularclientsecret"
      }.to_json

      api_response = http_client.post("/oauth2/token", body)
      response = JSON.parse(api_response.body)

      if response["access_token"]
        { access_token: access_token }
      else
        { error: "autentication error" }
      end

    end

    private

    attr_reader :http_client
  end
end
```

What I know is that curl in the following format is correct and I can see User's access token, refresh token etc.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
"grant_type": "password",
"username": "test+user@example.com",
"password": "examplepassword",
"client_id": "particularclientid",
"client_secret": "particularclientsecret"
}' "https://auth.xxx.com/oauth2/token"
```

But when I run my curl

```
curl -X POST -d 'email=test+user@example.com&password=examplepassword' "http://localhost:3000/api/auth"
```

I see that my request is not correct. But I have no clue where is the problem because header and body are formatted to JSON (I have entered `puts headers`, `puts body` and `puts response` to verify that).

```
Started POST "/api/auth" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-03-31 16:42:26 +0200
Processing by Api::AuthenticationController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"email"=>"test user@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}
{"Content-Type":"application/json"}
{"grant_type":"password","username":"test user@example.com","password":"examplepassword","client_id":"particularclientid","client_secret":"particularclientsecret"}
{"error"=>"invalid_request", "error_description"=>"The request is missing a required parameter, includes an unsupported parameter value, or is otherwise malformed."}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 610ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


NoMethodError (undefined method `access_token' for nil:NilClass):

app/controllers/api/authentication_controller.rb:21:in `create'
```

**Is my request incorrect or the problem exists somewhere else?**
I am not experienced developer. Just trying to learn enough to start as a Junior RoR. I tried to find a solution on stack and on different sites but I am stucked. Even faraday docs does not help me much

Comment: in a block of code "AuthClient service" you set headers variable but did not use it in request. is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

When URIs are escaped, a `+` is used as a replacement for whitespace. As such, when your controller un-escapes the URI, the `+` is changed back into a space. If you want to send a space, use `%2B` instead.

For your first problem, the error message indicates that `db_user` is nil when you try to do `db_user.access_token`. So, either `response[:access_token]` is nil, `api_user["id"]` is nil, or `User.create` failed.

You'll need to put in some debugging to find out where your problem is.

Comment: `I, [2017-04-01T00:50:34.680829 #23770]  INFO -- : post https://auth.xxx.com/oauth2/token`
     `D, [2017-04-01T00:50:34.681004 #23770] DEBUG -- request: User-Agent: "Faraday v0.11.0"`
     `D, [2017-04-01T00:50:34.681299 #23770] DEBUG -- request: {"grant_type":"password","username":"test user@example.com","password":"examplepassword","client_id":"particularclientid","client_secret":"particularclientsecret"}`

Comment: Hmmm it looks like my header is not even sent to the Client.